# What is catdvi used for in AucTeX?

Tags: auctex

In Ubuntu, AucTeX has an addon called catdvi. What is its use by AucTeX? Some other questions I have include:

1. How can I invoke catdvi in my gnome-terminal? `C-c C-c` will invoke a GUI viewer.
2. For TeX-PDF-mode, what command to view pdf files in terminal?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04 @King.

Comment: presumably related to `apt-cache show catdvi`

Answer (score 6):

CatDVI translates a TeX Device Independent (DVI) file into a readable plaintext file. It aims to generate high-quality output that reproduces all aspects of the DVI file within the limits of the output medium. CatDVI uses Unicode internally and can output ASCII, ISO Latin 1 and UTF-8 Unicode.

CatDVI can be used for previewing TeX documents on character-cell displays such as traditional terminals and terminal emulators. It is also possible to use it in generation of plain text documents from TeX source, assuming that the document is written with this conversion in mind.

CatDVI is under development and as such yet incomplete. However, it is quite useful even in its current form and already outperforms some of its competition in some areas.

CatDVI requires that the TFM files for all fonts used in its input DVI files are installed or can be generated by kpathsea.

In order to invoke catdvi from the gnome-terminal, just type:

```
catdvi file
```

In many systems less uses lesspipe, which can handle pdftotext automatically. Therefore, you can immediately try:

```
 less file.pdf
```

Which will show the output of pdftotext in less.

Source: [catdvi](http://archive.debian.net/lenny/tex/catdvi)

Comment: (1) How can I invoke catdvi in my gnome-terminal? C-c C-c will invoke GUI viewer. (2) For TeX-PDF-mode, what command to view pdf files in terminal?

Comment: I will answer that. Just edit into your question, and I will edit into my answer.

Comment: yes. done already

Comment: Can I call `less file.pdf` from emacs in AucTeX?

Comment: @Tim -- Sure.  Just do something like `M-x shell` (or `eshell`), then `less file.pdf` if you are in the directory where the file is.  `M-x shell` | `M-x eshell` opens a new buffer running (probably in your case) bash.